# Size of bootstrap input field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have:

```
<input name="test" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here" size="4" maxlength="4">
```

But the input box still takes up 100% of width.

If I remove the botostrap class `form-control` then I obviously lose the styling, but the box takes up the 4 character width I intended.

How do I get it to take the width of 4, while also keeping the bootstrap styling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of `.form-control` class ,which is bootstrap default class, you have to inherit this class.

for example:-

*This is default*

```
.form-control {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: 100%;
```

}

Use like this:-

```
<div class="wrap">
   <input name="test" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here" size="4" maxlength="4">
<div>



.wrap .form-control {
        background-color: #fff;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
        color: #555;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 34px;
        line-height: 1.42857;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        /*width: 100%;*/ remove this
}
```

Hope i'll helps you.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything in there which would be stopping me from putting an input box and a select box side by side? For some reason it's putting the select box on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple add new class with class="form-control new-input" like below

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control new-input">
```

Css

```
.new-input{width:100px}
```

thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a local styling, somehow like:

```
<input name="test" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here" style="width:<size value here>" maxlength="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input id="test" name="test" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-group #test{
    width:50%!important;
}
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blayderunner123/snupre3o/)